# $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} (y-\sin(y))/(x^2+y^2)$

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, functions

$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0), \\[6pt]
\dfrac{y-\sin y}{x^2+y^2} & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$

is $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \dfrac{y-\sin y}{x^2+y^2} = 0 \text{ ?}$

according to wolfarm no but can someone show me why?

Comment: how? and what do you get is it true or false?

Comment: can you show me the full steps please? I have also -sin(r*sin(Q))/(r*r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with functional analysis, but this question seems to be just a typical limit.

We will show the limit is $0$.

Observe that
$$\left|\frac{y-\sin y}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\frac{\left|y-\sin y\right|}{x^2+y^2}\le\frac{\left|y-\sin y\right|}{y^2}$$ so it is enough to prove that $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\left|y-\sin y\right|}{y^2}=0$. This can be done with the well known inequality $\frac{t^3}{3!}\ge t-\sin t$ for $t\ge 0$, or $\frac{|t|^3}{3!}\ge |t-\sin t|$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: so is it true that the lim=0 ?

Comment: yes, I edited and wrote the answer

Comment: but according to wolfarm there is no limit !

Comment: @STD : If $0 \le \left|\dfrac{y-\sin y}{x^2+y^2}\right| \le (\text{something depending on } y) \vphantom{\frac{}{\displaystyle\int}}$ and that "something depending on $y$" approaches $0$, then $\left| \dfrac{y-\sin y}{x^2+y^2} \right| \to 0.$ And if $\left| \text{another thing} \right|\to 0$ then that "other thing" approaches $0. \qquad$

Comment: I know but try to but it in wolfarm

Comment: @STD : I think one might have to know the exact input and output to Wolfram in order to address that. $\qquad$

Comment: ok, I tried in in Wolfram. It says the limit does not exist and it then also says "value may depend on $(x,y)$ path in complex space". So I thought maybe it's because we did all this using only real numbers and Wolfram is allowing complex numbers. But even then I think $\lim=0$ is correct. $\qquad$

Comment: . . . . and now I've resolved the issue. The limit exists if $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ but not if $(x,y)\in\mathbb C^2. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

I have upvoted tong_nor's answer. Then I tried Wolfram and it said the limit does not exist, and "value may depend on $(x,y)$ path in complex space". So I thought maybe it's because we did all this using only real numbers and Wolfram is allowing complex numbers. Let's try that:

Suppose the "path" along which $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ is $x = iy$ (a $2\text{-manifold}$ since $y$ has both a real part and an imaginary part). On that "path" the function is undefined although the numerator is no problem.

So if $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ approaches $(0,0)$ then this fraction approaches $0,$ but if $(x,y)\in\mathbb C^2$ approaches $(0,0)$ then the fraction does not have a limit.

Answer (score -1):

Now, One of the clasical method for obtaining the limit of function with two variables in $(0,0)$ is by this fact that you can 
assume $x=r \, \cos(\theta)$ and $y=r \, \sin(\theta)$, then calculate the limit with new values for $x$ and $y$ when $r \to 0$, if after calculation limit, the final values of limit depend on to $\theta$, we conclude that, the function dose not have limit in $(0,0)$ but if the final values of limit be independent of $\theta$, we say the function has limit in $(0,0)$ with value that we obtained. so we have

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\,\dfrac { y-\sin(y) } {x^{2}+y^{2} }
=\lim_{(r) \to (0)}\frac{r\,\sin(\theta)-\sin(r\,\sin(\theta))}{r^2}
$$
$$
\lim_{(r) \to (0)}\frac{r\,\sin(\theta)-\sin(r\,\sin(\theta))}{r^2}
=\lim_{(r) \to (0)}\frac{\frac{1}{3!}r^3\sin^3(\theta)}{r^2}=
\lim_{(r) \to (0)}\frac{1}{6}r\sin^3(\theta)=0
$$
that means your limit exist in $(0,0)$.

Comment: This is not correct.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Is it possible to ask you to say what is wrong in my answer. Thanks

Comment: To begin with, you have a $+$ instead of a $-$. Independent of this, replacing $(X,Y) = (r\cos t,r\sin t)$ in the limit does not give what you claim it gives. Look at it carefully.

Comment: $$ \overbrace{\frac{Y-\sin Y}{X^2+Y^2} = \frac{r\sin\theta - \sin(r\sin\theta)}{r^2}}^{\Large\text{right}} \ne \overbrace{\frac{r\sin\theta}{r^2}. \qquad}^{\Large \text{wrong}} $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy The limit of zero on the bounded function is zero then we have $$\lim_{r\to 0}\sin(r\sin\theta)=\sin(0)=0$$

Comment: @Amin235 : You cannot discard a term in the numerator because it approaches $0$ when the denominator also approaches $0.$ For example: $$ \lim_{x\to0} \frac{3x} x = 3 \text{ but } \lim_{x\to0} (3x) = 0.  $$ You can't just throw away the $3x$ merely because it approaches $0.\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I know what you mean like this example $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^3}$, but is difficult to me to extend to this question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I have a one question. When $r\to 0^+$ and $r\to 0^-$ what is the value of $\theta$?

Comment: @Amin235 $\theta$ does not depend on $\alpha.$ You either need to get a result that is independent of $\theta$ or else do something more elaborate.

Comment: @MichaelHardy based on the your answer I edit my question. Thanks